# Unable to Access CRM Data From Remote Machine using LINQ & SDK

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using following code to access CRM data from a remote VM, via early bound class Xrm.cs.

```
var query = (from c in xrm.ContactSet
where c.Telephone1 == callersNumber
select new Contact
{
FirstName = c.FirstName,
ContactId = c.ContactId,
});
```

When I run this code from my own machine it works perfectly fine as per expectation. But when it is deployed on the remote Machine, it throws exception and won't let me access data on CRM. When I check in browser I can successfully access the CRM but programmatically i am stuck. Kindly provide some help to hunt down this error, as it seems to be an issue with ports or security settings on the VM.

Following is the snippet from the exception stack.

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
```

Regards

Comment: Can you post the innter `FaultException`, too ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to un-synced date of two servers. We synchronized time but missed date, that was the main reason for this error.
Both time and date of the CRM Server & Application Server(hosting code), should be same, otherwise this exception will be thrown.